# How to install vcruntime140.dll without admin rights?

Tags: installation, php, dll, non-admin

I am starting to learn PHP, and installed php. The problem is that I need vcruntime140.dll to be able to run PHP. But it requires admin rights. Is there any way I can install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install this requires Admin rights. There is not any real way around that. Can you get your IT admin to install it for you?

Answer (score -1):

Just put the dll in the same directory as the exe file that you are trying to run.

https://www.dll-files.com/vcruntime140.dll.html