# how to install vcruntime140.dll on a surface tablet?

Tags: email, dll, microsoft-surface, email-client, microsoft-surface-3

in the context of:

[How to install vcruntime140.dll without admin rights?](https://superuser.com/q/1519982/977796)

I am looking to install this library on an older microsoft surface 3 tablet.  For some reason, the `alpine` mail client requires this `dll` (I'm not using `Python`).

The file is illegal or something?  Or illegal to share?  That seems questionable, but is what the answers on that question indicate.

I have admin access to Windows 10.

per:

https://www.dll-files.com/vcruntime140.dll.html

this looks to be related to installing `C++` -- which isn't going to work on a tablet.  (Or so I'd expect.)

Comment: There's no reason Visual C++ cannot be installed on a tablet. What leads you believe it will? Have you just tried installing the Visual C runtime? That's how this file is usually delivered, and absent a good reason, the way it ought to be delivered.

Comment: I think he needs this one first: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685

Comment: I think @Ramhound hit the nail on the head.  the salient point here is the processor.  pretty sure it's not x86.

Comment: storage one these devices is limited @music2myear so while it might install, I certainly wouldn't want to run an IDE on a tablet!  Just need the `dll` so far as I know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ repository](https://superuser.com/questions/1257160/microsoft-visual-c-repository)

Comment: yeah, I think installing C++ is a bit extreme to just run alpine/pine so I wouldn't consider that a usable answer.  If it's the only answer, then yes.  I'm hoping there's a work-around.  As to the processor, yes, atom makes sense.  I'll double check.

Comment: it's just a surface tablet.  I don't mind installing c++ or ide's, but storage and memory are constrained on the device.  thanks for the help, pardon any friction -- you're always quite helpful.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders It's a redistributable package. It's not an IDE, SDK etc. - just a bundle of libraries required to run software built with Visual C++. Don't overthink it.

Comment: You need the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Runtime Redistributable.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** selectively drop a `.dll` from a Microsoft (or others) runtime library into `%windir%\system32` or the `bin` folder of an application, and expect an application to work.

`vcruntime140.dll` is a component of the Microsoft C++ runtime library. Each of the DLL's in this library will be inter-dependant, meaning you'll be playing a game of whack-a-mole for the next few days, dropping in DLL's it depends on.

To prove this, open `vcruntime140.dll` with `Depends.exe`/Depenedancy Walker and await the results. It'll show you the intricate web woven between the DLL's in the library.

*[I'll update the answer with the output of depends.exe, once it's finished its analysis]*